# Unable to start a program as admin with "runas"

Tags: windows-10

I'm trying to give access to certain program, because it ask for admin privilegues. Because i don't need to give to the user the entire privilegue of local admin i just create this query in the direct access:

```
C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:P688N001\software /savecred "C:\Basic16\BIN\deco.exe"
```

The localuser "software" is a local admin, but still the cmd warns me with:

"This operation requires elevation (740)"

I tried everything and nothing is working.

Comment: Are credentials for the user `software` saved in the current user's profile? Are you aware that if you succeed at what you're doing here you'll enable your non-privileged user to run *other* programs with elevated rights, thereby entirely defeating their not being granted admin permissions?

Comment: I know about the risks but so far isn't working so isn't important i want to know if i can achieve this in WIndows 10

Comment: Please answer my first question.

Comment: Have you tried suggestions in this similar thread: https://serverfault.com/questions/734320/allow-standard-user-to-run-program-as-local-admin-without-elevation-prompt

Comment: Read over my answer here for the details for security considerations, etc. when doing this.... https://serverfault.com/questions/734320/allow-standard-user-to-run-program-as-local-admin-without-elevation-prompt/734360#734360. I know this post was linked above too but I've had to do this for some doctors before for that BlueStack software to run for some sort of emulated droid environment, etc. That company let their developers do whatever but the policy was no local admin access and granting explicit to the program file directory and the typical reg keys didn't work thus that workaround.

Comment: Local admin accounts in this domain environment had no access to any PHI data, etc. either as those were locked down by NTFS permissions and not accessible by computer AD object or any local computer admin account (just a specific AD security group only). Their policy also stated their people stored no local PHI on any local HDs and we had some elaborate things in place to ensure that was the case plus bit locker TPM fully encrypted all HDs on all PCs and laptops.